# How to set up a web server?

Tags: php, html, web, webserver

I have been asked to setup an online web server (e.g, digital ocean) and describe the steps I took. (e.g, installing and configuring private keys, firewall and web server).
And also what steps did I take to secure my setup?

I know very basic about php and HTML and this my first time setting up an online web server. My main question is that to set up an online web server I must pay money and buy space or I should use my own PC as a web server. which one is easier? I am trying to stick to the above question. Any help or reference to guide me will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few elements to consider here, for the server, you need this

- computer
- operative system (windows, linux, mac, ...)
- setting user access and user restrictions
- setting a firewall
- set remote access if needed (ssh, vnc)

For the web part of the question, you need this

- web server software (apache, lighthttpd, nginx, iis, ...)
- server side programming/scripting language if needed (perl, php, asp, ...)

If you can use a PC that you already have, use that one, after, you will have to mae that computer reachable from the exterior, for that, you have so give your external IP to the people that is going to use it, if you have a fixed ip, use that one, if you don't, then use something like [dyndns](http://dyn.com/dns/).

Of course, if you have a router, then you have to configure that router to pass the requests to port 80 to your PC serving as web server. You can start learning about that process with this [search about setting a NAT](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+set+a+nat&ka=c&kl=us-en&kp=-1&ks=m&ky=%23CBF2ED)

You don't have to use a dedicated machine for this, you can also use a virtual machine on your existing system, check [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), one of the easiest to set up.

All that are just the most basic steps, some are very simple, some are more complex. Definitely you don't have to buy/rent a server, although, it may be easier that doing all the work yourself. If this is for a school/university assignment, check the conditions applied and if you can use a PC/virtual server on their machines. If this for work, hire somebody that knows how to do it and if you want to learn, stay close to that person.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This is a test project for job interview. I have 5 days time to finish this:
Setup an online web server (e.g, digital ocean) and describe the steps you took. (e.g, installing and configuring private keys, firewall and web server).
What steps did you take to secure your setup?
Write a web application using the languages and technologies of your choosing that consists a minimum of two pages.

Comment: I have already paid $5 to DigitalOcean to buy space. Am I on the right track?

Comment: being a paid service, they already have many things up and running, I'm not completely sure about what is installed and configured there, so you should have to set some elements, but you are the one that has to check that. But I don't think that is going to work, since you don't have to set things like the firewall, which is an important part. The web server, I think is already installed, so it also doesn't count as something you have done. Check the community section to see what they have and what ou have to do and decide it that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm paying would probably be easier but you wouldn't learn anything.

My advice would be download Debian linux and install it to a computer you don't use. Then install apache.

Debian is pretty easy to install, they supply a gui, but there's also a guide [here](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/installmanual) that's very in depth.

Also apache is as easy as `sudo aptitude install apache2`, and your documents will need to be in /var/www to show up online. Make sure your ports are forwarded. A good guide, again, is the Debian documentation [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Apache).

As far as securing it goes, make sure ssh only accepts keys, and not passwords. Also close any ports you don't need.